# Sumifs with index and match

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup, sumifs

I have 2 sheets (Sheet 1 and Sheet 2), with large set of data, where I have to sum based on a criteria (Line Items in Column B), as this is the only column that is matching in both sheets. How do I solve this? I have used the following formula, however it is giving me an error. In sheet 2, with the help of a formula, I need to sum up based on line item and drag it down. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Assume your data start from `A1`,

```
=LAMBDA(KEYS,DATA,ITEMS,MONTHS,
 MAKEARRAY(COUNTA(ITEMS),COUNTA(MONTHS),LAMBDA(ROW,COL,
  SUM(FILTER(INDEX(DATA,,COL),KEYS=INDEX(ITEMS,ROW),0))
 ))
)(B2:B10,C2:E10,G2:G6,H1:J1)
```

1. Name the ranges you are working on with `LAMBDA()`,
2. Use `MAKEARRAY()` to define the `ROW` and `COL` index,
3. `FILTER()` the `DATA` according to `ITEMS`,
4. `SUM()` the result of `FILTER()`.

---

If you are not familiar with Array Formulas, you can also use this instead:

```
=SUM(FILTER(C$2:C$10,$G2=$B$2:$B$10,0))
```

Put it into `H2` (of my example) and darg it left to right, top to bottom, should also work.

Comment: Hi. Thank you so much for your quick repsonse. This is really a complicated Formula and it is not working in the data set :(  I don't find MAKEARRAY and what is LAMBDA?

Comment: strange, I tested it in online excel and it is working lol, ```LAMBDA()``` is a function the allows you to declare variables for later use in other functions. You can learn more in this official link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67

Comment: ```MAKEARRAY()``` should also be available to Excel for Microsoft 365 Excel for Microsoft 365 for Mac Excel for the web, according to the official explanation:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/makearray-function-b80da5ad-b338-4149-a523-5b221da09097

Comment: Ah Ok. My head is spinnig around. I am at this problem since morning and I am not able to solve it. I can show it you and it is giving me error saying there is a problem with this formula. How do I share the screenshot. Sorry, I am new to Stackoverflow. Thanks

Comment: if you are not familiar with Array Formulas, you can also use this instead: ```=SUM(FILTER(C$2:C$10,$G2=$B$2:$B$10,0))```, put it into ```H2``` (in the example I've provided) and darg it left to right, top to bottom, should also work.

Comment: you can simply take a screenshot, and CTRL+V in your question I think.

Comment: =SUM(FILTER(C$2:C$10,$G2=$B$2:$B$10,0)) this looks like it is working, I need to check in silence as this is a large data set. I'll let you know again in case if I am stuck again. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Is there any other way I can communicate with you?? In case if the formula is not working as I want it to. I can share the original file with you and you can see where the problem is? Thanks

Comment: you can just leave a comment here or create a new question in case you found any issue

Comment: Hi. The formula is working. Howver, I want to know suppose the line items are not in sheet 1 and I want to keep that cell blank, how do i do it? I have tried ifferror but it seems not working. When I drag it down, it is giving me a figure even though that field is blank. Can you please help?

Comment: I have added the screenshot in my post.

Comment: ```suppose the line items are not in sheet 1 and I want to keep that cell blank``` Not sure what you want to achieve, can you explain more?

Comment: Would you consider sharing a demo sheet with dummies data of what you are working on and your expected output?

Comment: how do i share my file here? I dont see any tab to share my data. When I copy paste it is not working in tabular form, i am totally lost now.

Comment: the formula is working only when I do it monthly but when I drag it to the right, it is not taking the correct column no. Even though i have added the dollar sign

Comment: You should not change the dollar sign, the dollar signs inside my formula are designed to get the right data input for source when you drag the formula, if you change them, you will break the formula, and that is why it is better to use array formula as they don't have to consider the which range to add $ for drag.

Comment: in formula ```=SUM(FILTER(C$2:C$10,$G2=$B$2:$B$10,0))```, ```C$2:C$10``` is the source data, the formula should get a different column of input when drag from left to right, that is why I didn't lock the ```C``` column with ```$```, same do ```$G2```, the reason why ```2``` is not locked, is that the formula needs to get a different input from ```Line Items``` when you drag it top to bottom, you have to follow all the signs of the sample formula in-order to get it work.

Comment: Hmm...I think the problem is I have extra columns in between months and therefore it is not copying correctly..

Comment: if that is the case, it could be difficult to use simple formula to achieve your expectations, 
 you should mention your input clearly in your question.

Comment: I forgot that you are sticking with excel lol, how about try to use the online excel to reproduce a part of your document, so that you will be able to share a demo here? https://www.office.com/launch/excel

Answer (score 0):

You may use SUMPRODUCT combined with unary operators and MATCH to get this:

[image]

Formula in cell K2 is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($B$2:$B$10=$J2)*--(COLUMN($C$2:$E$10)=MATCH(K$1,$C$1:$E$1,0)+2)*$C$2:$E$10)
```

Just drag to right and down

[SUMPRODUCT and Double Unary Operators](https://sprestridge.net/excel/2016/04/06/SUMPRODUCT.html)

Notice the formula combines a MATCH with a `+2`. This `+2` is because COLUMN function returns absolute column number and MATCH works only on selection. Because your months start in column C (third one) you need to add 2 to make COLUMN and MATCH work in the same references. If your month starts in column E would be +4, column F +5 and so on.

Comment: The formula is not working in my file, when I drag it down there is a spill.

Comment: @AshSam123 it should not spill. Try embebbing whole formula into a `SUM` and check